# What is the difference between these 2 select statements that use Count functions? SQL Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

```
Select Rating_Code as "Rating", Count(Rating_code) as "Total Movies"
From Movie
Group by Rating_code
Order by count(Rating_code) desc;
```

and

```
Select Rating_Code as "Rating", Count(*) as "Total Movies"
From Movie
Group by Rating_code
Order by count(*) desc;
```

They give the same results from what I can see

Also, when would use `Count(rating_code)` instead of `Count(*)`?

Comment: Check this thread: https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::NO::P11_QUESTION_ID:1156159920245

Comment: Oh whoops thank you both!

Comment: It's not a duplicate, because there is another 'real' difference, Count(Rating_code) doesn't count nulls, see this fiddle [link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=2e33b26ecde39882ec00c5cbc90d2db2)

Comment: Exactly, @Turo is right. The other question compares `count(1)` and `count(*)`, this question is about `count(rating_code)` vs `count(*)`

Comment: Until this question will be reopened, here is an answer:
The documentation of `COUNT` says 'If you specify expr, then COUNT returns the number of rows where expr is not null. If you specify the asterisk (*), then this function returns all rows, including duplicates and nulls'.

Comment: @KoenLostrie maybe you'd like to change your mind, too

Comment: If `rating_code` is defined as `NOT NULL` then the two are identical.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thats right, but 'Also, when would use Count(rating_code) instead of Count(*)?'

Comment: @Turo you're correct I wrongly assumed the user wanted a ```count(*)```

Comment: @KoenLostrie Only fair, In this use case (grouping by Rating_Code) only count(*) makes sense, but changing the grouping makes all the difference...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using count with column name only counts non-null values.
In your case would be the differnce if you'd have unrated movies, see this [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=2e33b26ecde39882ec00c5cbc90d2db2)

[image]

This starts really making sense if you group by other column(s), not (only) Rating_code...

For the preference of count(1) over count(*) see the comment of Koen Lostrie.

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/COUNT.html#GUID-AEF08B79-024D-4E3A-B362-9715FB011776) of `COUNT` says

> If you specify expr, then COUNT returns the number of rows where expr
> is not null. ... If you specify the asterisk (*), then this function
> returns all rows, including duplicates and nulls.

Your case is a bit more special as you group by a column and count the same column, which is a bit unusual. Your second query is more widely used and well understood, I'd say. People reading your first query will likely need to pause, check the nullability of the column and try to understand what your goal was.

I believe that the column syntax came into being to answer questions like "How many movies are rated", and "how many different rating codes" are there:

```
SELECT COUNT(rating_code), COUNT(DISTINCT rating_code) FROM movie;
```